# Retrieve DATA from XML with Simplexml

Tags: php, xml, symfony, soap, simplexml

I am trying to extract values from the XML SOAP response working with Symfony2 and php 5.6 and I've read the doc and tried many methods but still can't get the data

Here is my XML string

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <S:Body>
  <ns2:provisioningWithDataResponse xmlns="URL" xmlns:ns2="http://URL">
    <ns2:provisioningReturn>
        <date>2016-02-26T09:17:49.648+01:00</date>
        <messageId>642176832</messageId>
        <returnCode>1</returnCode>
        <returnMessage>Code: 6 Message: SQL query failed </returnMessage>
     </ns2:provisioningReturn>
  </ns2:provisioningWithDataResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I've tried this to get the data and store it in a session but it seems that `$xml` is always empty as I always get this error message

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Code:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($order_return);
$session->set("Respense",(string)$xml->children('ns2',true)->provisioningReturn[0]->returnMessage);
```

Any Idea how can I retrieve `returnMessage` value for example ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below:

```
(string)
// $xml is the node: S:Envelope
$xml->children('S', true) // => node: S:Body
    ->children('ns2', true) // => node: ns2:provisioningWithDataResponse
    ->children('ns2', true) // => ns2:provisioningReturn
    ->children() 
    ->returnMessage
```

Comment: That worked thanks .. Just one more question why you've put one S node and two ns2 nodes ?

Comment: Thank you .. now it all makes sense!